# SQLite strftime slow?

Tags: performance, sqlite, strftime

I have a table with around 1M entries.

The main request used on this table is :

```
SELECT SUM(count_value),strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00.000', created_at) as timestr FROM mytable GROUP BY timestr
```

which give me this kind of results :

```
123540  2018-02-01 15:32:00.000
225000  2018-02-01 15:33:00.000
```

Unfortunately the use of strftime seems pretty slow. The above request took around 2.5s to return 8 lines of results.

In comparaison the following request

```
SELECT SUM(count_value) FROM mytable GROUP BY created_at
```

took only 400ms to return more than 500 result.

Same performance for :

```
SELECT SUM(count_value),created_at as timestr FROM mytable GROUP BY timestr
```

The data set is not spread on wide datetime range (few minutes) but i dont think this is relevent.

**Is there a way to improve the speed of strftime ?**

note : the goal of the request is to sum up a value a get result grouped by minutes.

**UPDATE 1**

As asked : 
The DB scheme :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
created_at TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT(strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%f', 'now')), 
uuid TEXT NOT NULL,
count_value INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

CREATE INDEX idx_date_cpt ON mytable(created_at ASC);
CREATE INDEX idx_uuid_cpt ON mytable(uuid ASC);
```

And the result of an explain

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT SUM(count_value),strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00.000', created_at) as timestr FROM mytable GROUP BY timestr

selectid    order   from    detail
0   0   0   SCAN TABLE mytable
0   0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, for a more apples-to-apples comparison, how long does `SELECT SUM(count_value),created_at as timestr FROM mytable GROUP BY timestr` take in comparison?

Comment: it take around 400ms. updated my question to make that clear

Comment: Show the database schema, and the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: @CL.updated my question

Comment: `strftime` should be very fast and only applied to the results. You might be getting bitten by disk caching. The first time you use the database the OS has to read it off the disk. Each subsequent call might be from a much faster memory cache. It's also possible it reused that temp b-tree for subsequent queries if the table hasn't been modified. Be sure to run each query several times to be sure. You'll also might want to try an index on `timestr` to help the `group by`.

Comment: Running the query multiple time give each time a slow result. So no caching here i guess. timestr is just an alias , the aliased field is already indexed.